# Use Decode in Loop statement in Oracle PL/SQL

Tags: sql, string, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I want to use decode in Loop statement in oracle but unable to do so. This is my query

```
             for cur1 in
                    (
                         select distinct nvl(COVID_RISK_ZONE_NAME, 'No Data') "COVID_RISK_ZONE_NAME" from covid_daily_status
                    )
                    loop
                    VparaText:=VparaText||''''||cur1.COVID_RISK_ZONE_NAME||''' AS ' || '"'|| cur1.COVID_RISK_ZONE_NAME||'",';
                    
                    VselectText:=VselectText||'x."'||cur1.COVID_RISK_ZONE_NAME||'"'|| ' AS ' || '"'||
decode(cur1.covid_risk_zone_name, 'No Classification' , 'Market Opened', 'No Data', 'No Info Avlbl' , cur1.covid_risk_zone_name)||'",';

                    end loop;

                select SUBSTR(VparaText, 1, LENGTH(VparaText) - 1) into VparaTemp from dual;  
                
                select SUBSTR(VselectText, 1, LENGTH(VselectText) - 1) into VSelectTemp from dual;
```

I m getting this error: [Error] PLS-00204 (195: 106): PLS-00204: function or pseudo-column 'DECODE' may be used inside a SQL statement only

Why I can't use decode in Loop.

Comment: http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_pls_00204_function_pseudo_column.htm

Answer (score 2):

You could use `case` instead of `decode()`, or use the `from dual` trick. But bottom line, I don't hink that you need a cursor and a loop here. You can get the result you want using string aggregation:

```
select
    listagg(
        ''''
            || covid_risk_zone_name 
            || ''' as "' 
            || covid_risk_zone_name 
            || '"', 
        ', '
    ) into VparaText,
    listagg(
        'x."' 
            || covid_risk_zone_name 
            || '" as "' 
            || decode(covid_risk_zone_name, 'No Classification' , 'Market Opened', 'No Data', 'No Info Avlbl' , covid_risk_zone_name) 
            || '"', 
        ', ') into VselectText
from (
    select distinct nvl(covid_risk_zone_name, 'No Data') covid_risk_zone_name 
    from covid_daily_status
) t
```

Note that the subquery is not strictly necessary (you could use `listagg(distinct ...)` instead - but it avoids repeating the `nvl()` expression again and again.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the decode section as part of SELECT INTO from DUAL. You might try

Declare a new variable `VselectTextNew`

```
select VselectText ||'x."'|| cur1.COVID_RISK_ZONE_NAME||'"'|| ' AS ' || '"'|| decode(cur1.covid_risk_zone_name, 'No Classification' , 'Market Opened', 'No Data', 'No Info Avlbl' , cur1.covid_risk_zone_name)||'",' 
                into VselectTextNew from dual;
```

Replace the last part for the new variable

Comment: Thanks after a bit of modification to this my query is now working

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunally decode is not a really function. It is an expression and it is cannot be used in PL/SQL. Only in SQL statements.

Comment: Completely accurate, but why "unfortunately"? We now have CASE, which should be used instead.

Comment: I like decode and use it cuz often it is shorter than CASE if I need check equality multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of thanks to @GMB, @Roberto Hernandez and @akk0rd87 for their help.
To complete my query I had used @Roberto Hernandez trick but his query had to be modified as it always gave me the last part of loop in string as "select VselectText" was always resetting my string, so had to modify it a bit.

```
for cur1 in
                    (
                         select distinct nvl(COVID_RISK_ZONE_NAME, 'No Data') "COVID_RISK_ZONE_NAME" from covid_daily_status
                    )
                    loop
                    VparaText:=VparaText||''''||cur1.COVID_RISK_ZONE_NAME||''' AS ' || '"'|| cur1.COVID_RISK_ZONE_NAME||'",';
                    
                    select VselectText ||'x."'|| cur1.COVID_RISK_ZONE_NAME||'"'|| ' AS ' || '"'||
                     decode(cur1.covid_risk_zone_name, 'No Classification' , 'Market Opened', 'No Data', 'No Info Avlbl' , cur1.covid_risk_zone_name)||'",' 
                    into VselectTextNew from dual;
                    
                    vLong := vLong||VselectTextNew; --- Added new string.
                    

                    end loop;

                select SUBSTR(VparaText, 1, LENGTH(VparaText) - 1) into VparaTemp from dual;  
                
                select SUBSTR(vLong, 1, LENGTH(vLong) - 1) into VSelectTemp from dual;
```

I ll also try @GMB query as I was facing some issue in using the query directly.